# How to handle/track multiple events on a textbox (made by other elements onchange, onblur, onclick)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text boxes Area, length, height like

```
[spinner BTN-A(+)] 
     <input type="text" name="total_area" id="abc" value="0"> 
[spinner BTN-A (-)]

[spinner BTN-B (-)]
         <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="0">
[spinner BTN-B (-)]

[spinner BTN-C (-)]
        <input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="0">
[spinner BTN-C (-)]
```

Here `[spinner BTN-{A|B|C} (+|-)]` are spinner HTML button which increment/decrement text box value by 1.(0 on load)

I want to fetch values of all text's boxes. for that i am triggering common function `calculate()` using jquery trigger,

```
function calculate() {
  //javascript Code to calculate area
}
```

In existing code i am using onchange, onblur, onclick and many more events just to check if there is change in values of textboxes.

Is it possible in jquery to write a common trigger that handles all change in particular textboxes regardles of whether which event is changing it (onchange, onblur, onclick)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
       // the code here will execute whenever a value changes
});
```

Note that `onclick` event doesn't change the value of your text inputs, but if you want to handle it too, you can just add it like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input click', function() {
       // will execute on value change + onclick
});
```

Comment: Ok. What i understood is, If i manually change value of this text box or text box value is changed by any other button, i can access value of textbox in above code?  Thanks

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND No, this will only execute on user input, (whether by keyboard events or `onpaste`). But if you set the value programmatically no events will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery on, you can bind an eventhandler to several events at the same time: https://api.jquery.com/on/

The specification is:
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
events
Type: String
One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

You could use is as:
$("input").on("click blur change", your_eventhandler);